# Howto select a ASP.NET Core action from a JSON property in the body?

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a REST interface endpoint like

> POST /items/12345/actions

I utilize a generic actions sub collection to be apply to apply changes to 12345 which are not easily mapped to the content or direct other sub collections of it.

My question is the following: Since there could be multiple different action types I identify the action by a JSON property of the content of an uploaded document.

How do I select a action by a part of the JSON body of the request. Is there something possible like...

```
[Route("api/v1/items")
public class ItemsController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost("{id}/actions")]
    [CheckJsonBody("type", "ActionA")]
    public ActionResult DoActionA(int id, ActionA a)
    {
         // do something
    }

    [HttpPost("{id}/actions")]
    [CheckJsonBody("type", "ActionB")]
    public ActionResult DoActionB(int id, ActionB b)
    {
         // do something
    }
}
```

The request would look like ...

```
{
   "type": "ActionA",
   "abc": "xyz"
}
```

I have digged myself up into the code till `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionConstraints.ActionMethodSelectorAttribute` ([GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ActionConstraints/ActionMethodSelectorAttribute.cs)).

However starting from there, I am a bit lost to reach a high-performance solution. Do I need to decode the body or is that something which is already done at that time the constraint is evaluated?

ps: And yes, I know I could handle them in one action and do a switch on the "type" property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An ASP.NET team member was so friendly to direct me to an answer: In the `ActionMethodSelectorAttribute` you can read the body into a memory stream, read till the property for the selection filter. Then you seek the memory stream to zero and replace it in the request (for later model binding). You can cache the criteria value in `HttpContext.Items` to speed it up if you use the same property for multiple actions.

Comment: No. I never implemented it.